# Can a hybrid electric turboprop reduce fuel consumption 30% on regional flights?

Tags: altitude, turbine

UTC has a hybrid electric research project called [Project 804](https://www.aviationtoday.com/2019/03/28/utc-hybrid-ev-regional/), in which it claims that augmenting takeoff turbine power with electric power allows a smaller turbine for cruise, thus saving 30% of fuel burn. The target is a Dash 8 with a two megawatt engine on one side.

[image]

The plan is to combine a one megawatt turbine with a one megawatt electric motor powered by batteries, which motor is only used at takeoff. Since cruise power required is often only half of takeoff power, the smaller turbine can be used at its most efficient design point during takeoff and cruise.

However, the [following graph](https://www.flight-mechanic.com/gas-turbine-engine-performance/) shows altitude effects on turbine engine power. It looks to me like you already need a two megawatt turbine on the ground in order to get one megawatt around 20kft so it doesn't seem like the opportunity for savings even exists. What am I missing and how would this hybrid work?

The Dash 8 service ceiling is 25kft limited by lack of passenger emergency oxygen.

[image]

Comment: Probably not, because unlike automotive engines, aircraft engines are almost always run at a large fraction of their max power.  There's also no real equivalent to regenerative braking.

Comment: I would not board a plane that needed to run it's engines at about 90% pwr at cruise... not even 80%.

Comment: @Jpe61: Then you should probably never fly in a small plane :-)  Or at all: a bit of searching finds that a 737 cruises at 80% or more of full power.  But even 75% power is still a large fraction, compared to the 10-20% (or less, if you have a big engine) used by cars cruising at highway speeds on a level road.  For instance, my Honda Insight used a mere 17 hp or so on the level.

Comment: Yea might have exxagerated just a tad bit there

Comment: All i  all, there's not much point into this "invention".

Answer (score 1):

Turboprops are, like helicopter turboshaft engines, flat rated by having a large ITT surplus margin at sea level that allows a given torque limit (and therefore shaft HP at a specific RPM) to be maintained to higher altitude until the ITT/TOT limit is reached.

Not sure what the flat rating effects are on the PW-100 engines, but you can assume that a half-size version producing say 1000 hp instead of 2000 hp can produce most of that 1000 hp up toward its service ceiling, depending on how much ITT margin there is for a given engine's overall condition.

It seems that they want to try to work around the electric power limitation of low power density per pound of overall weight of motor and battery (about half of the turboprop with its kerosene probably) by only using the motor for short periods, then making the poor turboshaft engine run right at its limits just to cruise, where its specific fuel consumption may be a little lower than a larger engine taking it easy to make the same power.

To me it might be better to use the turboshaft engine to supplement and/or charge the battery and use an electric motor to power the whole thing, like a diesel electric submarine.

Comment: If the point is to use the turbine at its limit during cruise, wouldn't it be simpler to just not flat rate the engine? That way you get a small turbine producing 2kw at takeoff, forego unused excess capacity from flat rating and get the desired 1kw in cruise for efficiency. You don't need any of the weight or complexity of electric motors or batteries.

Comment: I'm thinking the concept is a bit like using a small gas motor in a car for highway cruising, which only needs to produce 15-20% power at highway speed, with an electric motor for acceleration only.  The small gas engine runs at its torque peak all the time, getting the best SFC.  If the turboprop gets its best SFC when running at peak torque, than it makes sense maybe to use a smaller engine that runs flat out at cruise, supplemented with electric for acceleration and climb.  Myself I think the idea is kinda dumb while electric power still has less than half the power density of fuel based.

Comment: If I had to guess I'll bet that this project is to burn off a "green" government research grant. You can get grant money for pretty much anything if you stick global war.... errr.. "climate change" in the preamble.